# UITableView has extra space on top during "pull down to refresh"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I have a problem with my tableview.
It has a space on top like this:
[image]

When I open the TasksTableViewController, the problem doesn't show. But when I open another viewcontroller from TaskTableVC like this:

```
 FilterTasksTableViewController * fttvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FilterTasksTableViewController"];
fttvc.delegate = self;
UINavigationController * navVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PopoverNavigationController"];
[navVC setViewControllers:@[fttvc]];
[self presentViewController:navVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and go back to TaskTableVC, the problem occurs.
When I "pull down to refesh", it goes back to normal.

in my code for TaskTableVC:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
//other code
[self populate];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

   self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];

    self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@" "];

    [self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [self setRefreshControl:self.refreshControl];

});

    [self populate];
}

- (void)populate {

TaskHandler *handler = [[TaskHandler alloc] initWithContext:_context];
NSArray *allTasks = [handler getAll];

_tasks = [self filterTasks:allTasks];

NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"startDate" ascending:NO];
NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor, nil];
_tasks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[_tasks sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors]];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
});

}
```

I hope you can help me with this weird problem.

Comment: What are you returing in the `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;` UITableView Delegate Method ? I think your UITableViewCell's Height is incorrect.

Comment: Hi, you just need to open translucent = True or just add one extra view b/w table and your main view. currently, your table is first subview view in your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem with the code. 
I thought there was something wrong with the `Refresh control` so I moved it out of the `dispatch_aysnc(dispatch_get_main_queue()` and added `[self.tableview reloadData` . That fixed my problem. Thanks everyone for answering. :)

Answer (score 0):

In view `viewWillAppear` set .

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)]) {

    [self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeBottom];

}
```

hope it help you .

Comment: UIRectEdgeBottom change it to  UIRectEdgeTop

Answer (score 0):

You Need to make Sure that your `UITableViewCell` has correct Height.

For doing that you can simply implement the `UITableViewDelegate` method :

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  return 90.0f; //CHANGE TO YOUR DESIRED HEIGHT. 
}
```

I hope this helps.